# How can I unit test a component which dispatches an action in reactjs/redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a reactjs component that has a method doSomething:

```
doSomething()
{
    this.setState({
        checked: !this.state.checked
    }, function () {
        if (this.state.checked) {
            store.dispatch({type: 'SOMEACTION', data: true});
        }
    });
}
```

What would the chai/mocha unittest look like for this method/component? How can I test a dispatch has called?

Answer (score 3):

Replace the dispatch with a spy and check that is was called with the correct arguments.

You can test that your action correctly dispatched to reducers correctly in another unit test somewhere using [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store).

You can also use [redux-mock-store](https://github.com/arnaudbenard/redux-mock-store) to mock the store here.

Although why are you calling dispatch on the store directly? You usually want to just call it on the props like so: `this.props.dispatch()` as dispatch gets passed automatically when you use `mapStateToProps`. This would mean you could just pass a spy down as a prop instead and not have to mock out the entire store.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [expect](https://github.com/mjackson/expect), for instance use spy to ensure the method is called as well as assert that state has changed.

```
// spy on the method to assert that it has been called
const doSomething = expect.spyOn(ExampleComponent, 'doSomething');
// simulate some behaviour
...
// assert method called
expect(doSomething).totHaveBeenCalled();
// assert state changed
assert.equal(store.getState()..., ...)
```

Also, you can split this into multiple tests.